# Can I connect from an Android device to my router from anywhere (outside of LAN - not hosted database)?

Tags: connection, ip

TLDR: i'd like to connect from a mobile phone app to a database on my RPI from anywhere on the world. Is it possible without hosting an URL or udpating the IPs in the app and being it free?

Longer version: if I set a static local IP to my RPI, can I somehow connect to the router from anywhere on earth via the internet? I'm making an app for employees to log their work around our country and I would give them out the .apk to install, so I'd like to make it always working (even if router restarts, etc). Is it possible via code (C#) or is there a free service that could allow me to do it? (service to set a global static ipv6 to RPI?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://ngrok.com/ or https://localtunnel.github.io/www/ (The default server for this is down these days) on your raspberry pi to receive a URL for a web service hosted on it.

If your router gets a public IP from your ISP, you can configure port forwarding on it to your raspberry pi, such that it forwards all connections to `router-ip:port` -> `raspberrypi-localip:port` and use a dynamic dns service like http://www.duckdns.org/ to give a "domain name" for your router instead of using the IP.

There are a lot of ways to do this really, but i say look into ngrok or if possible, the dynamic dns approach.